# Insert variable into the HTML from the input data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to insert price into the html element, which I'm getting from the input "data" value.

First function is working perfect, but second one is always giving 0.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($('input[name="bedrooms"]').is(':checked')) {
        var bedroomPrice = $('input[name="bedrooms"]:checked').data('price');
    } else {
        var bedroomPrice = 0;
    }

    $('input').on('change', function() {
        $('#total').html(bedroomPrice);
    });

});
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The first part only runs when page loads and nothing will change value of `bedroomPrice` after that

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. How stupid from me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using assigning value to a variable only when page loads. Actually you need to update the value of the variable when your input is changed.
Here is updated JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bedroomPrice = 0;
    $('input').on('change', function() {
        if ($('input[name="bedrooms"]').is(':checked')) {
            bedroomPrice = $('input[name="bedrooms"]:checked').data('price');
        } else {
            bedroomPrice = 0;
        }
            $('#total').html(bedroomPrice);
    });
});
```

Now it checks bedroom prices when the input gets change, which is latest value.

Also if you have multiple bedrooms choices and you want to show only price of the checked checkbox (considering user can check any 1 checkbox only at the time).
User `this` (which is the current element object) instead of `input[name="bedrooms"]`.
So JS code will becomes like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bedroomPrice = 0;
    $('input').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            bedroomPrice = $('input[name="bedrooms"]:checked').data('price');
        } else {
            bedroomPrice = 0;
        }
        $('#total').html(bedroomPrice);
    });
});
```

Hope it will work for you.